# Guide.BeginShowMessageBox Argument Exception

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I am trying to write a Username selector. What is does is create a LinkedList of all usernames (just strings) and then adds two other strings for New User and Cancel. The problem is that when I try to add the extra two strings Guide.BeginShowMessageBox(...) begins throwing an Argument Exception.

Looking at the actual layout of my List shows that it has a null entry at the end. Is their any way to get rid of this? I have also tried using a List and encountered the same problem.

Here is my current code:

Note that MogadeController.Mogade.GetUserNames() gets all previously used usernames.

```
LinkedList<string> names = new LinkedList<string>();
ICollection<string> col = MogadeController.Mogade.GetUserNames();
foreach (string s in col)
   names.AddLast(s);
names.AddLast("New Username");
names.AddLast("Cancel");
IAsyncResult fres = Guide.BeginShowMessageBox("Select New User", "Select a username to use or select New Username to create a new user", names, 0, MessageBoxIcon.None, null, null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940233.aspx).

> **The maximum number of buttons is two on Windows Phone**, and three on Xbox 360 or Windows.

You will have to create your own UI if you want to provide the user with more than two options.

Comment: I was worried about that. Is there any library that you know of that would get the same appearance without me having to redo most of my UI?

Comment: I don't think there's a `Guide` method for showing a list of options. I don't have WP7 so I can only guess. But I'd say that, to get a similar appearance, you'd need to look at using Silverlight + XNA. Personally I'd only go this route if my game were WP7-only and GUI-heavy. Otherwise I'd simply put up an option selection screen in-game.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it and see what I can put together.